# ios 9 swift not showing initial controller

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

I have my app with a custom splash screen to load some data from internet. In iOS 8 I can see this ViewController, but in iOS9 I only see it in the first launch of the app the rest of the launches iphone pauses on springboard and then shows the list of data that should be visible after the custom splash screen.
I don't know if there's some bug with ios9 related to this topic :(

Here's is my code, hope anyone can help me.

```
    class SplashScreenVC: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
  @IBOutlet weak var splashImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)


}

func rotated() {
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)) {
      splashImageView.image = UIImage(named:"eva_splash_landscape_")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)) {
      splashImageView.image = UIImage(named:"eva_splash_portrait_")
    }

  }

func startActivityIndicator() {
    self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
    self.spinner.center = self.view.center
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.spinner.frame.size.height = 50
    self.spinner.frame.size.width = 50
    self.parentViewController?.view.addSubview(spinner)
    self.spinner.startAnimating()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Storyboard files could be disconnect from your build target. Make sure Main Interface is your Main.Storyboard file and Launch Screen File is your Custom storyboard file [image]

Comment: Hi, I already have this configuration right [link](http://i.imgur.com/fmqXnlM.png) any other idea? thanks for the help